# Database with hash column in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an application in which I use a database that already existed and already has several data that I can not change.

I want to access this data using ActiveRecord, but the problem is that several of these models have a column called `hash` and ActiveRecord raises the exception:

```
ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError: hash is defined by ActiveRecord
```

What can I do to not override the hash method and the same time manage to access this column?

Comment: i guess that this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909501/how-to-override-a-column-in-rails-model

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510875/how-can-i-use-activerecord-on-a-database-that-has-a-column-named-valid-dange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [safe_attributes](https://github.com/bjones/safe_attributes) gem. Looks like it is built for your problem.

Comment: i really don't want to use a gem