# Rails: Using same name of Table field for Model method. Can this work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Say I have a `Users` table with a `first_name` field. Automatically I have a `User` model.

What I wan't is to know if it is possible to make a method also named `first_name` in the `User` model work?

I might do some modification inside the method. Say the model and the method would look like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def first_name
    # I know there are many ways to do this, this is just an example.
    "Mr. #{first_name}"
  end
end
```

I'm getting `SystemStackError: stack level too deep` in the console. Just wanna know if this is possible or if this can work.

Comment: have you tried self.first_name ?

Comment: @Noriel I used `read_attribute(:first_name)` its working now.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `read_attribute` method

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def first_name
    # I know there are many ways to do this, this is just an example.
    "Mr. #{read_attribute(:first_name)}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @deril. Actually found same solution here > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909501/how-to-override-a-column-in-rails-model. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Cool, it helped me a lot, thanks!